# PivotTable - Replace #N/A when using Show Value As

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a PivotTable in Excel 2013 where the first column is a standard aggregate value, and the second column uses the "Show Value As, % Difference From" menu selection for the same measure.  In some subcategories, the member that the other values are compared to is missing.  When this happens, Excel displays the "#N/A".  Is there a way to suppress the #N/A and show either a blank or a different character string?

```
DIMENSION           DOLLARS       % DIFF FROM MEMBER 3
                                  IN THAT SUBCATEGORY   
CATEGORY A          
    SUBCATEGORY A1      
        MEMBER 1     $6,115         -3.14%
        MEMBER 2    $12,304     94.90%
        MEMBER 3     $6,313 
        MEMBER 4     $6,657      5.45%
        MEMBER 5     $6,329      0.25%

    SUBCATEGORY A2      
        MEMBER 1     $5,459      #N/A
        MEMBER 2     $5,051      #N/A
        MEMBER 4     $8,217      #N/A
        MEMBER 5     $4,569      #N/A
        MEMBER 6     $3,882      #N/A

    SUBCATEGORY A3        
        MEMBER 1     $8,003      8.25%
        MEMBER 2     $8,675     17.34%
        MEMBER 3     $7,393  
        MEMBER 4     $7,564      2.31%

CATEGORY B      
    SUBCATEGORY B1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the pivot table and choose 'PivotTable Options'. You should see the following dialog:

[image]

As indicated above, check the box saying "For error values show:" and put whatever you want in the entry box next to it. If you leave it empty, you'll get blanks.

Comment: Duh... Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!